# Exception handling problem

Tags: java, exception, coding-style

I noticed that lots of developers are performing all kind of checks by using utility classes, I mean that, for example, `SomeDefenseClass.checkState(arg > 4)` and so on. It seems to be pretty nice and clean way for checking arguments, application state, null pointers etc. util it's okay to throw only IllegalStateException for state check. NPE for null pointer and so on. But I'm facing a problem now: I have to throw a lot of different exceptions for different kind of illegal states e.g. ItemNotFoundException, UserNotAuthorizedException and so on..

So I can think three solutions for this problem but unfortunately no one seems to be good enough

1) Easiest way: not to use utility class at all and just write if blocks. (Just don't like to have so many

```
if (!foo) {
    throw new SomeException(arg1); 
}
if (!bar) {
    throw new SomeOtherException(arg1, arg2);
}
// and so on
```

2) To write a different stateCheck method for every possible exception (Not so good, cause we have about 30 different exceptions and counting)

3) To write one method to defense class:

```
public static void checkState(boolean condition, Throwable t) {
    if (!condition) {
        throw t;
    }
}
```

Anyway in this case I have to create new Exception object every time the state check is performed and that means that thousands of totally unnecessary objects are created and at the end of a day it may become a problem :)

So, can anyone recommend a good solution for that problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading your first paragraph, I am sensing that you are trying to mix business exceptions (ItemNotFoundException, UserNotAuthorizedException) with class level assertions (checking arguments, application state, null pointers).

Business Exceptions are like the contracts to the API and should be meaningful to the business like you have. It is better to create and throw them from where they belong. This not only is a good encapsulation but PRESERVES the correct stack trace thus helping to debug the problem easier.

Assertions are mainly for internal logic verification and are there to find the logic errors, developers mistakes etc early in the test cycle than in the production. Ideally assertions are turned ON while development and testing and turned OFF in production. Preconditions, Postconditions and Invariants are 3 kinds of assertion categories. Learn more about [Design By Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

There is no real need to move the assertion checks to utility methods. Plan to use the Java's built-in [assert keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) and enable them during development and testing. My suggestion for you is to use assert keyword for invariants and postcondition checks and use [google-guava's Preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/package-summary.html) for checking preconditions.

If you see that there are common validations being performed at multiple places then it is better to encapsulate them into its own class for e.g. AgeValidator, SalaryVaidator etc (DRY principle). Again no need to build your own framework here, use the standard java spec [JSR 303 Bean Validation](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/01/getting-started-with-jsr-303-beans.html).

Answer (score 1):

I hate the idea of a utility class performing these checks.

My first thought would be "keep the contract enforcement inside the object that requires it".  Using a utility class provides an economy of reuse that's false.

My second thought would be a binding and validation framework, like the one Spring has.  Bind input from the UI into objects, validate it, and move on.  This seems more reusable to me; Spring is the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/) or similar frameworks